# Solving a system of equations with squared x's and exponentials

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to solve the next system, and give the solutions as vectors.

$ x e^y - x^3 = 0 $

$ x^2 e^y - e^{4y} = 0 $

I was doing

$ x e^y - x^3 = 0 \Rightarrow x(e^y - x^2 )=0  $

$ \Rightarrow x=0 $ o $ x= \pm \sqrt{e^y} $

Then, if $ x=0$, substitution in the second equation implies that $ e^{4y}=0 \Rightarrow \ln (e^{4y})= \ln (0) \Rightarrow y = -\infty$??

If $ x= \pm \sqrt{e^y} $, subtitution in the second equation gives me $e^{3y}=e^{4y} \Rightarrow \ln (e^{3y})=\ln (e^{4y})  \Rightarrow 4y - 3y = 0 $ $ \Rightarrow y=0 $

From which I would get that

$ x= \pm \sqrt{e^0} \Rightarrow x= \pm 1$

I am not sure that I am right..

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $x = 0$ is not a solution, since the second equation implies $e^{2y} = 0$, and this equation has no solution either since $e^{2y} > 0, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus $x \neq 0$, and the first equation gives: $x(e^{y} - x^2) = 0 \to x^2 = e^{y} \to e^y\cdot e^y - e^{4y} = 0 \to e^{2y} - e^{4y} = 0 \to e^{2y}\left(1-e^{2y}\right) = 0 \to 1 = e^{2y} \to y = 0 \to x^2 = e^0 = 1 \to x = \pm 1$.